# Javascript for loop, index variable in function

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to figure out how to generate functions inside for loop.
I have:

```
for (var i = fir_0_f.length - 1; i >= 0; i--){
  var next = i+1;
  var N = i;
  // Attemps
      //goal0_[i](next,N);
      //eval('goal0_'+i+'('+next+', '+N+')');
};
```

Have done also some searching. [] expects a string, eval() is a B.A.D practice. Is there any other way?
How to set the timeout for each function later? So they would run sequentally?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Can you show the code where the functions are defined? Changing that might simplify things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for (var i = fir_0_f.length - 1; i >= 0; i--){
  var next = i+1;
  var N = i;
  setTimeout('goal0_'+i+'('+next+','+N+')', 0);
}
```

Note: errors thrown by goal0_*i* won't be caught by the loop.
I've noticed this behavior in Firefox.
That means that the following won't work as you expected:

```
try{
   setTimeout(function_throwing_error, 0);
}
catch(e){
   alert("I kill you!");
}
```

Answer (score 4):

In JavaScript you could use function expressions to build an array of functions:

```
var goals = [];

goals.push((function (param1, param2) {
   // your code for the first function
}));

goals.push((function (param1, param2) {
   // your code for the second function
}));

// ... etc
```

Then in your for loop, you can simply reference your functions as elements of an array:

```
goals[i](next, N);
```

**UPDATE:**

To call your functions with a delay between each other, you'd have to change your loop logic. Instead of using a `for` loop, call the first function immediately, and then after it runs, make it call the second one using a `setTimeout()`.

Comment: Good idea. How then run each function with timeout in for loop?
First would execute immediately, others with timeout.

Comment: @c4rrt3r: Updated my answer with a comment on the timeout.

Answer (score 0):

For global functions, you can just do:

```
window['goal0_'+i](next, N);
```